# XMLReader IsElementEmpty is Wrong

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, xml-parsing

So I am building a little Windows Form application which allows you to select a message off an MSMQ queue, and then display the XML Message in a nicely formatted viewer on a dialog form. The dialog form uses a Rich Text Box control.

Once the Body of the message is read into an XMlDocument. I have created this extension method to add line breaks and formatting:

```
    <Extension()>
    Public Function Beautify(doc As XmlDocument) As String
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
        Dim settings As New XmlWriterSettings()
        With settings
            .Indent = True
            .IndentChars = "     "
            .NewLineChars = Environment.NewLine
            .NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace
            .Encoding = New UTF8Encoding(False)
        End With

        Using writer As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings)
            If TypeOf doc.ChildNodes(0) Is XmlProcessingInstruction Then
                doc.RemoveChild(doc.ChildNodes(0))
            End If

            doc.Save(writer)
            Return sb.ToString()
        End Using
    End Function
```

I create an List(Of String) so that multiple messages can be selected, and then I pass this into my custom constructor for the dialog form:

```
Public Sub New(lMessages As List(Of String))

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Dim strLastMessage As String = lMessages.Last()
    For Each strMessage As String In lMessages
        Using reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(New StringReader(strMessage))
            While reader.Read()
                Select Case reader.NodeType
                    Case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration
                        Me.rtbMessage.SelectionColor = Color.Blue
                        Me.rtbMessage.SelectionFont = Me.rtbMessage.Font
                        Me.rtbMessage.AppendText("<? " & reader.Name & " " & reader.Value & " ?>")

                    Case XmlNodeType.Element
                        Me.rtbMessage.SelectionColor = Color.Blue
                        Me.rtbMessage.SelectionFont = Me.rtbMessage.Font
                        Me.rtbMessage.AppendText("<")
                        Me.rtbMessage.SelectionColor = Color.Brown
                        Me.rtbMessage.SelectionFont = Me.rtbMessage.Font
                        Me.rtbMessage.AppendText(reader.Name)
                        If reader.HasAttributes Then
                            While reader.MoveToNextAttribute()
                                Me.rtbMessage.SelectionColor = Color.Brown
                                Me.rtbMessage.SelectionFont = Me.rtbMessage.Font
                                Me.rtbMessage.AppendText(" " & reader.Name)
                                Me.rtbMessage.SelectionColor = Color.Blue
                                Me.rtbMessage.SelectionFont = Me.rtbMessage.Font
                                Me.rtbMessage.AppendText("=" & Chr(34))
                                Me.rtbMessage.SelectionColor = Color.Black
                                Me.rtbMessage.SelectionFont = New Font(Me.rtbMessage.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
                                Me.rtbMessage.AppendText(reader.Value)
                                Me.rtbMessage.SelectionColor = Color.Blue
                                Me.rtbMessage.SelectionFont = Me.rtbMessage.Font
                                Me.rtbMessage.AppendText(Chr(34))
                            End While
                        End If
                        If reader.IsEmptyElement = True Then
                            Me.rtbMessage.SelectionColor = Color.Blue
                            Me.rtbMessage.SelectionFont = Me.rtbMessage.Font
                            Me.rtbMessage.AppendText(" />")
                        Else
                            Me.rtbMessage.SelectionColor = Color.Blue
                            Me.rtbMessage.SelectionFont = Me.rtbMessage.Font
                            Me.rtbMessage.AppendText(">")
                        End If

                    Case XmlNodeType.Text
                        Me.rtbMessage.SelectionColor = Color.Black
                        Me.rtbMessage.SelectionFont = Me.rtbMessage.Font
                        Me.rtbMessage.AppendText(reader.Value)

                    Case XmlNodeType.EndElement
                        Me.rtbMessage.SelectionColor = Color.Blue
                        Me.rtbMessage.SelectionFont = Me.rtbMessage.Font
                        Me.rtbMessage.AppendText("</")
                        Me.rtbMessage.SelectionColor = Color.Brown
                        Me.rtbMessage.SelectionFont = Me.rtbMessage.Font
                        Me.rtbMessage.AppendText(reader.Name)
                        Me.rtbMessage.SelectionColor = Color.Blue
                        Me.rtbMessage.SelectionFont = Me.rtbMessage.Font
                        Me.rtbMessage.AppendText(">")

                    Case XmlNodeType.Whitespace
                        Me.rtbMessage.AppendText(reader.Value)
                End Select
            End While
        End Using

        If strMessage <> strLastMessage Then
            Me.rtbMessage.AppendText(Chr(13) & Chr(10))
            Me.rtbMessage.AppendText(Chr(13) & Chr(10))
        End If
    Next
    Me.rtbMessage.Select(0, 0)
End Sub
```

Now most of this works great, except that self-closing elements are not getting a closing "/>". I would think my If-Then statement where I check for reader.IsEmptyElement would do the trick, but it does not.

The following is a sample XML file:

```
<Animal type="Mammal">
    <Classifications>
        <Classify name="CommonName" value="Dog" />
        <Classify name="Environment" value="Land" />
        <Classify name="NumLegs" value="4" />
    </Classifications>
</Animal>
```

If you run my code, you will see that the "Classify" elements are rendered without a tag closing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! If you know C# better, than a solution in that language is fine as well. I can convert!

Answer (score 0):

I guess I figured out my own question! LOL!

Just had to add:

```
reader.MoveToElement()
```

just after I am done reading all the Element Attributes. The reader was no longer on the element, but instead on the last attribute, and therefore IsEmptyElement was False.  If I move back to the element, the IsEmptyElement function works correctly.